# Как запустить главный поток по завершению цикла во втором потоке? на Си

Tags: c, многопоточность, event-loop

суть такая:
есть 2  потока.
главный(int main)
и  побочный(thread).
В побочный поток приходят извне данные, которые передаются в главный поток, где  обрабатываются, возвращаются обратно, далее  побочный  поток встаёт на ожидание через `uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);` , пока в него снова не придут данные и  снова обращается в главный  поток.

Тут начинается проблема: при попытках запуска через uv_async_t event, ничего не происходит.

пока единственное  решение, которое пришло мне в голову - запустить обработчик через `while(1)` или через `while(true)`,  но это криво и мне не нравится, т.к. loop  в  переводе петля, должно иметь какие-то простые функции, чтобы включать обработчик без такого примитивного зацикливания.

```
void thread_cb(void* arg) {
 loop1 = uv_loop_new();
 uv_loop_init(loop1);
  // тело функции получающее данные извне
/*тут хотелось бы задать какое-то элементарное событие, которое бы заметил наблюдатель 2 ого потока*/
 uv_run(loop1, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
 //return
}

void fun(void* arg){
 uv_mutex_lock(&abc.mutex);
 uv_cond_wait(&abc.cond, &comm.mutex);
//хрень, которую я  выполняю
 uv_cond_signal(&abc.cond1);
 uv_mutex_unlock(&abc.mutex);
 }

int main() {
 loop = uv_default_loop();
 uv_loop_init(loop);
 uv_thread_create(&abc.thread, thread_cb, (void*) &abc);
//сюда б наблюдателя... мысли наблюдателя: -"В loop1 свершилось событие, запускаем."
//как передать из побочного потока сигнал вот сюда, чтобы убрать "бес конечный" цикл?
while (1) {
 fun(&abc);
 }
 return uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);


}
```

хотелось бы узнать, как оно делается...

Comment: Не понятно зачем тут поток. Что за сигналы, что за хрень?

Comment: Зачем 2 лупа???

Comment: @eri ,  смотрите, есть задача, обязательно 2 потока, обязательно в каждом  свой луп,  и чтобы первый обрабатывал принятые вторым данные,  я понимаю, естественно, что задача решается в  одном потоке без такого идиотизма, но поставлены условия.

Comment: В либув 4 потока и колбэки выполняются в каждом по очереди..

Comment: т.е. возврат к  первому невозможен?

Comment: @eri , вот смотрите, `void sk(void* arg) {

 uv_mutex_lock(&abc.mutex);
 uv_cond_signal(&abc.cond);
 uv_cond_wait(&abc.cond1, &comm.mutex);
 uv_mutex_unlock(&abc.mutex);
}`  эта  команда из 2  потока отправляет  запрос наобработку данных первым потоком

Answer (score 0):

while (1)  можно заменить на uv_idle_t или uv_check_t. Но блокировка кондишна не даст обработать ответ от треда.

Выполнить колбэк в главном потоке из другого треда можно через uv_async_t

Comment: если долго заниматься интимом, то сточится не одна клавиатура, спасибо за совет, я подебил. всё же через async.